# Linear representation: basic definition-Example on group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am trouble to understand the following assertion.

We saw that a regular representation is a pair $(\rho,V)$, such that $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a homomorphism and $V$ a vector space. A following assertion states that giving a representation is somehow equivalent to give a map $\phi:V\rightarrow V$ such that $\phi^2=Id$. Then, provided that $Char(K)\neq 2$, $\phi$ is uniquely determined by a direct sum decomposition $V_+=\{v\in V\mid \phi(v)=v\}, \ V_-=\{v\in V\mid \phi(v)=-v\}$.

For this reason it will be assumed that $Char(K)\nmid \ \mid G\mid$. I see that if $Char(K)=2$ then $-1=1$ and so we would not have such a direct sum decomposition. But why should the equivalence actually fail? Moreover, by Cauchy theorem I see that if $Char(K)\nmid \ \mid G\mid$, then there must be an element $g\in G$ such that $2g=0$, but how is this going to exclude that $Char(K)\neq 2$?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have a bunch of assumptions not mentioned here. Otherwise the description of a representation in terms of a map $V\to V$ is not correct. Are you in fact looking at representations of the group with two elements?

Comment: Well actually I don't really get what's going on. He begin by considering the group of two elements but then states that it holds in general for $Char(K)\neq 2$..

Comment: Who does? A representation will obviously in general not be uniquely determined by any single matrix.

Comment: That's what I have from my lecture. I'm pretty confused... Do you may be see what is going on in the second part of my question?

Comment: So the description seems to be only for the group of order $2$. In this case, the only "problem" is if the characteristic of the field is $2$, in which case something a little strange happens. Note that the condition $\phi^2 = Id$ becomes $(\phi - Id)^2 = 0$ (due to the characteristic being $2$), which means that up to conjugation, $\phi$ is upper triangular with $1$'s on the diagonal. In particular, this gives you a subspace of dimension $1$ on which the group acts trivially, but which will not have a complement in general.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I understand your argument but how can I connect it imposing that $Char(K)\nmid\mid G\mid$