# linear representations, usual assumption

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $G$ a finite group. Working with linear representation we want to avoid the case where $Char(K)=2$. For this we assume always that $Char(K)\nmid \mid G\mid$. Why we assume this? Can I recover $Char(K)\neq2$ from the second assumption?

Here is my problem, considering the representation on the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, see link[Representation Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471584/linear-representation-basic-definition-example-on-group-mathbbz-2-mathbbz)

---

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to assume that the characteristic is not $2$?  The condition about the characteristic not dividing the order of $G$ is needed in order to make arguments involving averaging over the group, like in Maschke's theorem.

Comment: @Jez actually I'm still thinking at a my previous question, below I wrote the link to this. But then can you say me how do I have to read the following comment in the picture I uploaded here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471584/linear-representation-basic-definition-example-on-group-mathbbz-2-mathbbz

Comment: Since the group has order two, assuming the characteristic is not two is the same as assuming that the characteristic does not divide the order of the group...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ah... now I think I got it. What we want as a general condition is $char(K)$ not dividing the order of the group and in our example from this same condition we get that the characteristic of the field is not 2. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A representation of a group $G$ over a field $K$ is a group homomorphism $\rho \colon G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ for some $K$-vector space $V$.  A subrepresentation is a subspace of $V$ on which $G$ acts, i.e. which is closed under the action of the image of $\rho$.

Suppose $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$.  Then $G$ is generated by a single element, $g$ say, which satisfies $g^2=e$ (where $e$ is the identity).  To define a homomorphism $\rho$ from $G$ to $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ we need to specify $\rho(e)$ and $\rho(g)$.  But any such  group homomorphism has to send $e$ to the identity $I$ in $\mathrm{GL}(V)$.  So we only need to choose the value of $\rho(g)$, which we'll call $\phi$.  In order for this to be a homomorphism we must have $\phi^2=I$ (and this is sufficient too).

If $\mathrm{char} K \neq 2$ then any $\phi$ which squares to $I$ is diagonalisable and we can decompose our space $V$ into a direct sum of eigenspaces $V_+$ and $V_-$ of $\phi$, with eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$.  Each subspace $V_+$ and $V_-$ can be written as a direct sum of $1$-dimensional subspaces on which $G$ acts.  These are irreducible subrepresentations (i.e. they have no proper subrepresentations themselves).

In summary: if $\mathrm{char} K \neq 2$ then any representation of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ can be written as a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations; we say the original representation is completely reducible.  To see that this can fail if $\mathrm{char} K = 2$, consider $V=K^2$ and $\phi$ given by

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

This squares to $I$ but we cannot decompose $V$ as a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations.

The correct generalisation of this statement to other groups is that a representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $K$ is completely reducible if $\mathrm{char} K \nmid |G|$.  (This is *not* an 'only if' statement.)

Comment: very helpful. Thank you very much:)

Comment: You're welcome :)